# How to change background and text colors R commander?

Tags: r, user-interface, editor, r-commander

I would like to change the background and text colors of the R commander.
I can change the colors of the R GUI by changing the Rconsole file, and this works fine.
I can also change some options of the R commander by changing the Rprofile file. However, I haven't found any options regarding colors.

I would be grateful for any hints!

Comment: Try this package `devtools::install_github("r-lib/crayon")`

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Helps you do what you asked for.

Comment: Could you maye give me a hint about how I could use crayon to change background and text colors? I have installed the package and had a look at the documentation, but I'm not sure how to use it. The examples i tried did not seem to work immediately.

Comment: Just learnt that RGui doesn't support `crayon`.